# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial alternative for .NET Standard

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, .net-standard

I want to know if there is any alternative in .NET Core o .NET Standard for consuming Microsoft.VisualBasic functions.

I already know that in .NET Standard 2.0 that is in preview we can add .NET Framework dll without the [mscorlib issue.](https://github.com/dotnet/standard/blob/master/docs/netstandard-20/README.md)

But actually .NET Standard 1.6 is the stable version and I prefer no to use preview version.

Comment: To state the obvious, that is a very small library and the methods are all relatively simple and use algorithms that are readily found.  Why not just create your own implementation?

Comment: Maybe the code in this project will help http://cash4net.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thank's both, I will just creat one with the functions I need.